# hazelcast upgrade issue from 3.6.5 to 3.7.4

Tags: java, maven, arraylist, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Hi am upgrading hazelcast from 3.6.5 to 3.7.4 followed the instructions from hazelcast doc.

am getting an exception like:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.spi.impl.UnmodifiableLazyList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

i just upgraded hazelcast jar do i need to do any other jar upgrade?

stacktrace follows:

```
2017-01-24 11:33:44 ERROR error:162 - Exception occurred in class com.rathish.test.services.authentication.impl.LocalClient the exception details are: Exception: 
[errorCode  =  504,
 errorMessage  =  Failure - Unable to retrieve entity from database
    Detailed exception trace = 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.spi.impl.UnmodifiableLazyList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at com.rathish.test.services.authentication.dao.RoleDao.getRoleByUserId(RoleDao.java:367)
    at com.rathish.test.services.authentication.impl.LocalClient.authorizeCredentials(LocalClient.java:108)
    at com.rathish.test.services.authentication.AuthValidation.validateAuthorization(AuthValidation.java:420)
    at com.rathish.test.services.authentication.AuthValidation.loginValidation(AuthValidation.java:104)
    at com.rathish.test.services.authentication.AuthenticationService.login(AuthenticationService.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.process(ProxyServlet.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.doFilter(ProxyServlet.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.process(BridgeServlet.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeFilter.doFilter(BridgeFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.rathish.test.web.filter.SessionValidationFilter.doFilter(SessionValidationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.spi.impl.UnmodifiableLazyList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at com.rathish.test.services.authentication.dao.RoleDao.getRoleByUserId(RoleDao.java:367)
    ... 56 more
using along with maven

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please attach RoleDao class as well.

Comment: Judging by the stacktrace you're using `ArrayList` references instead of `List` references, therefore assuming the concrete type of an object (which was now changed).

Answer (score 1):

Based entirely on your stacktrace, your RoleDao class on line 367 is something like the following (variable and method names are entirely arbitrary):

```
ArrayList<Baz> foo = (ArrayList<Baz>)hazelCast.findById(bar);
```

This presumably worked before since the actual type returned *was* `ArrayList`. However it has since changed to `UnmodifiableLazyList`.

Solution is to always program to interfaces, and change the code to

```
List<Baz> foo = hazelCast.findById(bar);
```

(or `Collection<Baz>`, depending on what the API states as the return type).

Comment: This [Git commit](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/commit/035dcb3c53dbdfddc46d8dea2d81e36ae0b170df) is what I think you're referring to.

Comment: @asgs Looks like quite a possible culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it used to work in 3.6.x?
I'm looking at the history in github and it always used to extend the `java.util.AbstractList` like this:

`public class UnmodifiableLazyList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements DataSerializable {`

So it never used to extend `ArrayList`

Comment: Not an answer. Besides, the issue is not that it would have extended `ArrayList` at any point in time.

Comment: Thx for your kind answer. If it extended it the casting would work bro.

Comment: Yes, and then we wouldn't have this question. However the problem is with the casting itself. His code made assumptions about the concrete type, instead of using whatever interface the API returns. As you can see from the git commit in the comment to my answer, there were instances of `ArrayList` changed to use `UnmodifiableLazyList` instead. So the issue was never with whether `UnmodifiableLazyList` extended `ArrayList` or not.